# concatenated string in Pascal

Tags: save, concatenation, pascal, text-files, string-concatenation

I'm currently using a writeln command to write to a text file.

Is there any way to use concatenated string using record in pascal?

This is my pascal code currently:

```
Procedure SaveTopScores (Var TopScores : TTopScores);
    Var
    Count : Integer;
    CurrentFile : Text;
    Begin
    Assign(CurrentFile, 'HiScores.txt');
    Rewrite(CurrentFile);
    For Count := 1 To MaxSize
      Do Writeln(CurrentFile, TopScores[Count].Name, ',', TopScores[Count].Score);
      Close(CurrentFile);
    End;
```

And this is writing to the file in VB, is there a way to do a concatenated string in pascal?

[image: VB]

Comment: Which version? Newer Delphi versions have e.g. `Format()`

Comment: @Turbo J: I am using Dev-Pascal 1.9.2, here is the about screen. I don't know what version maybe this will help you? - http://cl.ly/0V1r3F2m203Y1l3p2m2K

Comment: You'll save yourself lots of headaches if you learn to properly format your code. The style (or lack of) you're using now is extremely hard to read, and very prone to errors. You've seen that in previous questions, like the missing begin..end that caused it not to compile. Also, please don't post images to code (like you did with the VB example above). It makes it unsearchable and, in the case of what you posted above, unreadable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `str1 + str2`. I think it's an extension on the original Pascal, but it should be quite common.

Comment: Updated code to: http://cl.ly/0s3p3T121O2B2g1K1C2J

But error is no 'Error: Incompatible types: got "LONGINT" expected "SHORTSTRING" on the "Do Line :=.

Is there a specific type of variable I should use?

Comment: You are adding integers to string and attempting to store those in a type of variable string. This can't work. Probably you want to change line to type string, and convert score to string using inttostr

Comment: Thanks it works now.

Problem is now when using this type of save, the existing scores are deleted and the new ones are written on the .txt.